# I was trying to build Aseprite following a tutorial but it doesn't work

Tags: c++, git, command-prompt

After I use

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DLAF_BACKEND=skia -DSKIA_DIR=C:\deps\skia -DSKIA_LIBRARY_DIR=C:\deps\skia\out\Release-x64 -DSKIA_LIBRARY=C:\deps\skia\out\Release-x64\skia.lib -G Ninja ..
```

In the command prompt I get this

```
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:17 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0046 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/CMakeRCInformation.cmake:27 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    C:/aseprite/laf/cmake/c_flag_overrides.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/Platform/Windows-MSVC.cmake:510 (enable_language)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/Platform/Windows-MSVC.cmake:488 (__windows_compiler_msvc_enable_rc)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/Platform/Windows-MSVC-C.cmake:5 (__windows_compiler_msvc)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:48 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:32 (project)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake:89 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    C:/aseprite/laf/cmake/cxx_flag_overrides.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:32 (project)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:36 (message):
  Your Aseprite repository is incomplete, initialize submodules using:

    git submodule update --init --recursive


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/aseprite/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I'm seeking help since I don't know what is happening right now.

I tried reinstalling CMake, restarting the pc, updating windows.
I hoped Aseprite would build normally.

Comment: Did you execute the command that CMake told you to do? `git submodule update --init --recursive` from the `C:/aseprite` folder

Comment: @drescherjm It said "fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

Comment: Then my expectation is you need to pull aseprite from github instead of how you installed it: [https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite/blob/main/INSTALL.md#get-the-source-code](https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite/blob/main/INSTALL.md#get-the-source-code)

Comment: @drescherjm I'll try it out and tell you what happens

Comment: That's exactly what was wrong, thank you very much.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Had to clone the git repo insted of downloading the zip file